# What is the difference betweeen MDM and EMM in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I found two products open sourced in Github called MDM and EMM of WSO2

I didn't get completely what is the difference btw both of them.

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 EMM is a unique mobile solution that is open source, user-friendly and distributed under the Apache Software License v2.0. WSO2 EMM includes two key aspects: Mobile Device Management (MDM) and Mobile Application Management (MAM). EMM enables organizations to secure, manage and monitor Android and iOS powered devices (e.g., smart phones, ipod touch devices and tablet PCs), irrespective of the mobile operator, service provider, or the organization. In addition, EMM also enables organizations to manage mobile application (app) life cycles via the Publisher, distribute mobile apps to users registered with EMM via the Store, and manage mobile apps (i.e., install and uninstall in bulk, blacklist, and more) via the EMM Console. EMM, maintains a compliance monitoring process to detect devices that are non-compliant to the assigned policy. In addition, EMM supports SSO and multi-tenancy.

Documentation - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/WSO2+Enterprise+Mobility+Manager

Features - http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/

Comment: OK I got it. Then the two products must be linked together. Is there any relation between the two solutions WSO2 opensourced. How do we integrate them together?

Comment: please find the links
additional information - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Additional+Resources

Comment: these links could be useful as well.
Connected Device Management (CDM) - http://www.slideshare.net/fullscreen/wso2.org/io-t-devicemanagement/1

MDM Documentation - https://docs.wso2.com/display/MDM200/WSO2+Mobile+Device+Manager

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM) is the term for the comprehensive security and enablement platforms that are evolving specifically for mobility.  Mobile Device Management (MDM) is one of the facets within a complete EMM solution, providing a broader set of tools for IT.  These include the ability to require a PIN lock, identify and exclude jailbroken or hacked devices, and the power to remotely lock the device in case of loss.  While today’s EMM products feature more granular and less intrusive controls, MDM features remain an important foundational piece of mobile enablement.

Comment: Thanks Utsav. If we take a look at WSO2 suite of products. what are the features that I get with EMM & MDM?

Comment: Please don't quote without attribution. http://enterpriseadoption.com/what-the-difference-between-mdm-and-emm-emm-expert/

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 MDM is of products which was in the 1st release (1.0.0) of WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager suite. MDM was targeted for managing Enterprise mobile devices (iOS & Android). Its other component is MAM which is targeted for managing Enterprise mobile applications. You can find that component in github. However in the latest release of WSO2 Mobility suite, MDM & MAM components were merged into a single product called EMM. It contains the bug fixes & some improvements also.